# Upper bound for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n - n^3}{\sqrt{n!}}$

Tags: summation

I am trying to find an upper bound to this expression

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n - n^3}{\sqrt{n!}}
$$

It is sure that the limit of the inner expression as it goes to infinity is 0 (which is neccesary, not enough), but I can't find a way to show that the sum exists.

Comment: Do you know Stirling's approximation for $n!$? (Interrobang not intended.)

Comment: Are you trying to compute an upper bound or simply show the sum converges? How good does the upper bound need to be, if that's what you're after?

Comment: I am trying to give some upper bound (maybe lower too if it converges from negative). The bounds don't have to very precise, just something with good reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 2):

For large $\,n\,$ we have [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n!\cong n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

and from here

$$\frac{2^n-n^3}{\sqrt{n!}}\cong\frac{2^n-n^3}{n^{n/2}e^{-n/2}\sqrt[4]{2\pi n}}\le\left(\frac{2e}n\right)^n\frac{n^{n/2}}{e^{n/2}\sqrt[4]{2\pi n}}$$

and if you now apply Cauchy's $\,n$-th root test to the right side term, we get

$$\frac{2e}n\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt e(2\pi n)^{1/4n}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0<1\;\ldots\ldots$$